# Malloc Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT) problem

Tags: c, malloc, signals, sigabrt

I am having a problem with my code using malloc. It has been working perfectly until an hour before. It causes on this line

```
                    temp2 = (Temp*)malloc(sizeof(Temp));
```

I've tried removing (Temp*) to see if that helps but it didn't. And when I searched my error message which is

```
untitled8(15926,0x1141ae5c0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fbff3c032e8: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x742e7962616c6c61
untitled8(15926,0x1141ae5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
```

The answers I found from the internet would something to do with free(), but it errored before when I free any malloced variables.

I have main.c and task1.c and task.2, also 3 header file, and the code below is from task1.c. Never wanted to post this long ass code but since I used malloc to the other part so I would like it to be checked as well... sorry for any inconvenience reading code in advance.

```c
typedef struct histogramTemp {
    char *words;
    int count;
    struct histogramTemp *next;
} HistogramTemp;

typedef struct temp{
    char c;
    struct temp *next;
} Temp;


HistogramTemp *task1(FILE *fp, char *fname){

    char textfile, *string = NULL;

    Temp *tempHead = NULL, *temp1, *temp2;
    HistogramTemp *uniqueWordTemp = NULL, *headTemp, *uniqueWordTempHead = NULL;


    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("\n\n!! Error in opening file !!\n");
        printf("Program will proceed with defult 'australia.txt' file. \n");

        FILE *defultFp;
        defultFp = fopen("/Users/katyang/CLionProjects/untitled8/australia.txt", "r");

        fp = defultFp;

    }

    while((textfile = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){

        // save temporary word as a separate char linked list 'Temp', and save it to 'string' as a whole word

        if (isupper(textfile)>0) {
            temp1 = (Temp*)malloc(sizeof(Temp));
            temp1->c = textfile;

            temp1->next = tempHead;
            tempHead = temp1;

            int i=0;
            while(tempHead != NULL){
                string = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(&string[i],&tempHead->c);
                i++;
                tempHead = tempHead->next;
            }

            while ((textfile = fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
                if (isalpha(textfile)>0 && !(isupper(textfile))) {
                    temp2 = (Temp*)malloc(sizeof(Temp));
                    temp2->c = textfile;

                    temp2->next = tempHead;
                    tempHead = temp2;

                    while(tempHead != NULL){
                        strcpy(&string[i],&tempHead->c);
                        i++;
                        tempHead = tempHead->next;
                    }
                }

                // use 'string', make Histogram
                if(isupper(textfile) || !isalpha(textfile)){

                    int flag=0;
                    int commonWordsFlag=0;

                    // check if the words are in the commonWords list
                    for (int j = 0; j < 122 ; j++) {
                        if (strcmp(string, commonwords[j])==0){
                            commonWordsFlag++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if((strlen(string)<3) || (commonWordsFlag == 1)){
                        break;
                    }

                    headTemp = uniqueWordTempHead;

                    // compare string to uniqueWordTemp
                    while (uniqueWordTempHead != NULL){

                        // increment count if the word is in Histogram
                        if(strcmp(uniqueWordTempHead->words, string)==0){
                            uniqueWordTempHead->count++;
                            flag++;
                            uniqueWordTempHead=uniqueWordTempHead->next;
                        }else{
                            uniqueWordTempHead=uniqueWordTempHead->next;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    // create new node if the word is not in Histogram
                    if ((uniqueWordTempHead == NULL) && (flag == 0)){
                        uniqueWordTempHead = headTemp;

                        uniqueWordTemp = (HistogramTemp*)malloc(sizeof(HistogramTemp));
                        uniqueWordTemp->words = string;
                        uniqueWordTemp->count=1;

                        // insert in head
                        uniqueWordTemp ->next = uniqueWordTempHead;
                        uniqueWordTempHead = uniqueWordTemp;

                    }else{
                        uniqueWordTempHead = uniqueWordTemp;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    createNewFile(fname, uniqueWordTempHead);

    free(string);
    free(tempHead);
    return(uniqueWordTempHead);

}
```

so, I expected to save data in temp2 a string. It seems working with debugging which is so strange.. I have no problem when I debugged but my program ended with exit code 11 every time when I execute the program.

**Edit**
I added a main.c and a header file of task1() for more information.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "task1.h"
#include "task2.h"


int main() {

    FILE *fp;
    char *fname = malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("\n\n:::::::::::::: TASK 1 ::::::::::::::\n\nPlease Enter the Full Path of the file: \n");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    fp = fopen( fname , "r");

    task1(fp, fname);
    HistogramTemp *uniqueWordTempHead = task1(fp, fname);
    task2(fp, fname);



    free(fname);
    free(uniqueWordTempHead);
    return 0;

}
```

header file

```
#ifndef UNTITLED8_TASK1_H
#define UNTITLED8_TASK1_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct histogramTemp {
    char *words;
    int count;
    struct histogramTemp *next;
} HistogramTemp;

typedef struct temp{
    char c;
    struct temp *next;
} Temp;

HistogramTemp *task1(FILE *fp, char *fname);

int countHistogram (HistogramTemp *head);
void printHistogram (HistogramTemp *head, FILE *fp);
void createNewFile(char *userFilename, HistogramTemp *head);



#endif //UNTITLED8_TASK1_H
```

Comment: You're probably overwriting a chunk of allocated memory before you get to that `malloc()`, so the control information is corrupt.  Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to identify where the problem is.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm currently watching youtube tutorial for valgrind and the sample code which meant to be very problematic looks exactly like mine... lol gotta get it fixed. thank you!

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` not `char`. It does this by intention.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: OT: regarding; `string = malloc(30*sizeof(char));`  1)  The expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.   2)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `task1()` is never called in the posted code

Comment: @user3629249 I added a header file if you would like to have a look. Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler using Valgrind is confusing for me since I'm not familiar with using a terminal.. do you have any other way you would suggest to find the problem?

Comment: regarding: `char *fname = malloc(sizeof(char));`  The file name is  a 'string', which means it will have a minimum of 2 characters. The first char being a single char file name the second char being the NUL termination byte

Comment: in the header file, should only `#include` header files that the header file actually uses.  I.E.  remove: `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: what about the contents of the header file: `task2.h`?

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", fname);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Those functions return the number of successful input format conversions.  Therefore, in this instance, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred  2) When using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]` always use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append just a `char` to a "string" like this:

```
    strcpy(&string[i],&tempHead->c);
```

`strcpy()` expects a pointer to a "string"'s 1st `char` as 2nd parameter. In C a "string" is an **array** of `char` with at least one `char` being equal to `'\0'`.

Use

```
    string[i] = tempHead->c;
```

instead and terminate `string` by doing

```
  string[i] = '\0';
```

Also here

```
          while(tempHead != NULL){
            string = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

`string` get allocate to with each iteration overwriting the point received in the previous iteration. This introduces a huge memory leak.

More the allocation out of the loop.

So this

```
        while(tempHead != NULL){
            string = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(&string[i],&tempHead->c);
            i++;
            tempHead = tempHead->next;
        }
```

would look like this

```
        string = malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        i = 0;
        while(tempHead != NULL && i < 29){ // one less to be able to store the '0' terminator
            string[i] = tempHead->c;
            i++;
            tempHead = tempHead->next;
        }
        string[i] = '\0';  // store the '0' terminator
```

Comment: I fixed the part you pointed. Thank you very much. But I am still having a problem with the part `temp1 = malloc(sizeof(Temp));` part.. I don't know what I am doing wrong since this program was working earlier.

Comment: When you have "it was working earlier”, the preferred solution is to save the current code and go back to the working version and reevaluate the changes made.  That assumes that you used some VCS in time to save what was working before you made the breaking changes. @KatYang

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well.. I've tried that and it didn't work either haha.. somehow I fixed the problem, but having another problem with file pointer.  I don't think I'd go to sleep tonight